Some of my SF users are seeing this error in a dashboard, when all of them have the same permissions
We just brought on 2 new sales people and they are the only 2 people who cannot view the widgets on the dashboards. I've double checked set up for each of them and they are identical to other employees. Why would they be getting this report when trying to view reports on a dashboard:
This report can no longer be edited or run. Your administrator has disabled all reports for the custom object, or its relationships have changed.

